# Querying Array data type in elasticsearch using python_dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

How complex can a query be on an integer array data type? Here is my class in python to inject data into `elasticsearch`:

```
class Paragraph(DocType):
    body = Text(analyzer="standard")
    published_from = Date()
    lines = Integer()
    n_paragraph = Integer()
    capture = Integer()

    class Meta:
        index = "my_index"

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.lines = len(self.body.split())
        return super(Paragraph, self).save(**kwargs)
```

I am injecting an array of integer in capture. Here is the interesting line :

```
paragraph.capture = [1, 0, 5, 7]
```

1. I manage to query if a number is in the list::

     `cnx =  Search().using(client)
     s = cnx.query("match", capture=5)`
2. as @Val said we can add another field that contains sum to query the sum

How to query a specific index e.g. `paragraph.capture[1] >= 1` ?

we saw that [Elasticsearch query on array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920911/elasticsearch-query-on-array-index) is related but I could not make the link.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to query the sum is to add another field that contains it so you don't have to run a costly `script` query at search time.

Querying if at least one number is superior to 4 can already be done with a normal `range` query on the `capture` field.