# Elasticsearch arrays of string query based on array index

Tags: arrays, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch documents which looks like below :

```
MetaData metadata,
... many other properties...
```

MetaData class :

```
public class MetaData {
private List<String> keywords;
}
```

Now I want to build a query which match the provided string to the `metadata.keywords`'s 0 index.

Code example : `metadata.keywords[0]` equals to input string

What I have done is below :

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
query.must(QueryBuilders.existsQuery("metadata.keywords"));
```

How can I specify the index to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

For Elasticsearch, arrays are like multivalue fields where the order of the values is not relevant, so there is no explicit search on an index position like `[0]`.

You might check this answer ([Elasticsearch query on array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920911/elasticsearch-query-on-array-index)) if this approach works for you (try the query out manually with some REST client). If it does, you will need to build the query with this filters using the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` from Spring Data Elasticsearch - although I cannot guarantee that all necessary operations are available.